# Ruby Padrino - Back button functionality

Tags: ruby, padrino

I am having difficulty with logging in and the functionality of the back and forward buttons associated with a user who is logged in. When I log into the application from the login page I am directed to a page (lets call it logged_home). If I press the back button I am returned to the login page. If I then press forward I am redirected to the "logged_home" page. The desired outcome when pressing the forward button at this point would be that the logged session is destroyed and if the person presses the forward button it remains or redirects back to itself i.e. login.

I have tried a number of approaches including clearing cache and destroying the session but havent found a workable approach as yet. In detail I have tried to instigate a session destroy every time the login page is loaded but it doesnt seem to work as intended. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to define a method in your controller to store this 'prev, next' values ?

Comment: What authentication mechanism are you using at the moment?  Are you just tracking a session variable to ensure the user is logged in, or using a pre-existing framework like `padrino-warden` ?